# List is populated into a dropdown, by selecting an option of other dropdown, but the complete column gets that row's options in a table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, parent-child

[image]
After selecting an option from a dropdown of a table row I call an api to get a list of String into a dropdown field for that row but the complete column gets that row's options.I want only that row particular to get manipulated. How to achieve this in angular js.
For example:
if I select India as countryName for an employee I get CountryStates from the api but the CountryStates o get populated to the complete column of that table. So I want it to get populated to that particular row.
Can  you please help me.
here is my code

```
<tr ng-repeat = "data in arrayOfEmp" id = {{$index}}>
<td>
<select ng-model="data.countryName" ng-options="country for country in countries" ng-change ='getStates($index)' unselectable="on">
{{data.countryName}}
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select ng-model="data.stateName" ng-options="st for st in stateNames" ng-change ='changeButtonStatus()' unselectable="on">
{{data.stateName}}
</select>
</td>
```

here is the code of the angularjs controller

```
$scope.arrayOfEmp = [{
    empID : '093024',
    countryName : 'India',
},{
    empID : '093214',
    countryName : 'USA',
},{

    empID : '0935614',
    countryName : 'Dubai',
}];
    
    
    
    $scope.getStates = function(id)
    {   $scope.stateNames = [];
        http({
        method:'GET'
        url:'getStateNames'
        params: {country : $scope.arrayOfEmp[id].countryName}
      }).then(function onSuccess(response){
               $scope.stateNames = response.data;
         },function onError(){
                  console.log(response.data);
               });
        
    }
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same stateNames for all of your rows, therefore when you update the value of stateNames with result of your API call all values are updated. What you can do is add stateNames to your arrayOfEmp and use that value.

1.

```
$scope.arrayOfEmp = [{
    empID : '093024',
    countryName : 'India',
    stateNames : []
},{
    empID : '093214',
    countryName : 'USA',
    stateNames : []
},{

    empID : '0935614',
    countryName : 'Dubai',
    stateNames : []
}];
```

2. change your select to

   ```
   <select ng-model="data.stateName" ng-options="st for st in data.stateNames" ng-change ='changeButtonStatus()' unselectable="on">
    {{data.stateName}}
    </select>
   ```
3. pass the row to ng-change

   ```
    <select ng-model="data.countryName" ng-options="country for country in countries" ng-change ='getStates($index,data)' unselectable="on">
    {{data.countryName}}
   ```
4. update the stateNames array in your row

   ```
    $scope.getStates = function(id,data)
     {   $scope.stateNames = [];
    http({
    method:'GET'
    url:'getStateNames'
    params: {country : $scope.arrayOfEmp[id].countryName}
    }).then(function onSuccess(response){
           data.stateNames = response.data;
     },function onError(){
              console.log(response.data);
           });

   }
   ```